# Which processes with daemon are unnecessary?

Tags: unity, python, ram, services, memory-usage

I saw 3 processes which have "daemon.py" at the end of them and use 10 MB of memory each of them. What do they make? Also there are a lot of processes which have daemon inside. Are they really necessary and is it safe to stop/remove some of them? If yes, how can I stop them permanently?

My current processes which have daemon inside in 13.10:

- bamfdaemon
- dbus-daemon
- gnome-keyring-daemon
- gnome-settings-daemon
- ibus-daemon
- ubuntu-syncdaemon
- unity_facebook_daemon.py
- unity-files-daemon
- unity_flickr_daemon.py
- unity-music-daemon
- unity_picasa_daemon.py
- unity_shotwell_daemon.py
- unity-video-lens-daemon
- zeitgeist-daemon

Comment: Does not Javier's answer answer your question? If it does, you can click on the accept icon :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a long list. I'll tell you this daemons functions, if they are necessary or not is probably a personal decision.

- **gnome-settings-daemon**: Manages themes and icons, if you kill it you aps while look funny using stock icons instead of the system ones. Fun to kill as it will only have cosmetical effects, but you will need to keep it in the long run.
- **gnome-keyring-daemon**: It stores passwords securely. If you kill it you will need to type passwords every time that they are needed (i.e. when connecting to a wifi network)
- **dbus-daemon**: This is used by lots of programs to talk with each other. You will need it.
- **ibus-daemon**: This is related to complex keyboard input. You only need it to support keyboards with non-occidental input systems, accessibility options, etc...
- **zeitgeist-daemon**: This daemons keeps different usage data, things like: recent used documents, most popular programs, etc...

If using Unity (default before 17.10):

- **bamfdaemon**: Matches windows with icons in the unity bar. It keeps a list that tells unity wich windows are associated with which icons. If you kill it, Unity will probably respawn it or start acting funny.
- **ubuntu-syncdaemon**: Ubuntu One sync. Needed if you are using [Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/).
- **unity_facebook_daemon.py, unity-files-daemon, unity_flickr_daemon.py, unity-music-daemon, unity_picasa_daemon.py, unity_shotwell_daemon.py, unity-video-lens-daemon**: These are Unity lenses, they return results when you search in the dash. Enable or disable them to customize your results. You can enable or disable them from the control center (prior 13.10) or from the dash itself (13.10)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Firstly I am new Ubuntu user so I need a little more help. I think control center is another name of system settings if so I could not find any setting about Unity lenses for disabling/enabling. I did not create Ubuntu One account because I do not need it. Therefore I turned off it from the panel but I still see its daemon in the system monitor.

Comment: Sorry, in 13.10 lens are disabled on the Dash itself, not in System Settings: http://askubuntu.com/questions/363912/how-to-remove-amazon-and-ubuntu-one-music/363951#363951.